# Content Filter + Samsung grid loading effects causes error on adding these two

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement the [Samsung grid loading effects](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SamsungGrid/index2.html) with the [Content filter](http://codyhouse.co/demo/content-filter/index.html) but when i use both there is a problem in the height(footer just overlaps with the content) and filter is not working properly please help me with it where i did wrong..

Sample code:

```
<ul class="cd-filters">
                <li class="placeholder"> 
                    <a data-type="all" href="#0">All</a> <!-- selected option on mobile -->
                </li> 
                <li class="filter"><a class="selected"  data-type="all">All</a></li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".latest-research"><a  data-type="latest-research">Latest Research </a></li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".consumer-intelligence"><a data-type="consumer-intelligence">Consumer Intelligence</a></li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".brand-insights"><a  data-type="brand-insights">Brand Insights</a></li>
                <li class="filter" data-filter=".whitepapers"><a data-type="whitepapers">Whitepapers</a></li>
            </ul>
<section class="grid-wrap cd-gallery">
                <ul class="grid-b swipe-down" id="grid">

                    <li class="mix latest-research"><a href="#"><img src="img/dummy.png" alt="dummy"></a></li>
                    <li class="mix consumer-intelligence"><a href="#"><img src="img/dummy.png" alt="dummy"></a></li>
                    <li class="mix brand-insights"><a href="#"><img src="img/dummy.png" alt="dummy"></a></li>
                    <li class="mix whitepapers"><a href="#"><img src="img/dummy.png" alt="dummy"></a></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

At-last I found a answer to my question both the jquery plugin uses inline styles to alter the content in `li` so i have to work on the inner jquery to alter and remove some functions so that the one effect runs at a time.

the code that conflicts in inline is

```
<li class="mix latest-research" style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#"><img src="img/dummy.png" alt="dummy"></a></li>

<li class="mix latest-research" style="position:absolute;"><a href="#"><img src="img/dummy.png" alt="dummy"></a></li>
```

so if i removed either `position:absolute;`or `display:inline-block;` it works charm